# multiple expression using ng-class to set and remove class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I saw others' solution but mine didn't work, probably there are snytax error because I'm applying multiple class.

```
ng-class="{'col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-8':item.lp_image!='', item.lp_image='','col-md-12'}"
```

Comment: You should describe in much more detail what you're doing, why are you doing it and why it doesn't work. Only then you'll receive answers, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

What you are defining in the `ng-class` attribute is a JavaScript object. You can define several rules, just like you define several properties of an object. Each key is a class, each value is a boolean or an expression that gives a boolean.

E.g.

```
{
    'class1': false,
    'class2': true,
    'class3': 2 == 2,
    'class4': 3.1415 > 0
}
```